# My Fifo buffer written in VHDL doesn't work

Tags: buffer, vhdl, fifo

i'm trying to write a Fifo buffer in VHDL, but i don't know why it isn't work very well. This si the code:

Mux:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

 entity Mux is
 generic (WIDTH : INTEGER := 8);
Port ( 
       SEL : in  STD_LOGIC;
       clk : in  STD_LOGIC;
       A   : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (WIDTH-1 downto 0);
       B   : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (WIDTH-1 downto 0);
       X   : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (WIDTH-1 downto 0));
 end Mux;

architecture Behavioral of Mux is
begin
process(clk)
begin
if(SEL='0') then
    X<=A;
elsif(SEL='1') then
    X<=B;
end if;
--X <= A when (SEL = '0') else B;
end process;
 end Behavioral;
```

Demux:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
package array_type is
type std_logic_vector_array is array (natural range <>) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0); 
end package;
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use work.array_type.all;
entity Demux is
generic (WIDTH : INTEGER := 8; CONTROLLER : INTEGER:= 2);
Port ( 
       SEL : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (CONTROLLER-1 downto 0);
       clk : in  STD_LOGIC;
       A   : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (WIDTH-1 downto 0);
       X   : out std_logic_vector_array(2**CONTROLLER -1 downto 0));
 end Demux;

architecture Behavioral of Demux is
begin
  process (clk)
 begin
 if (rising_edge(clk)) then     
    if(SEL="00") then
        X(0)<=A;
    elsif(SEL="01") then
        X(1)<=A;
    elsif(SEL="10") then
        X(2)<=A;
    else
        X(3)<=A;
    end if;
end if;
 end process;

 end Behavioral;
```

Flip flop D:

```
library ieee;
 use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity FF_D is
port (d, clk, rst: in std_logic;q: out std_logic);
end FF_D;
architecture behav of FF_D is
begin
    process (clk,rst)
        begin
            if (rst='0') then
                q<='0';
                --d<='0';
            else 
                if (rising_edge(clk)) then 
                    q<=d;
                end if;
            end if;
    end process;
   end behav;
```

Flip Flop d vector:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity FF_D_Vector is
generic (WIDTH : INTEGER := 4);
port ( 
    d: in std_logic_vector(WIDTH-1 downto 0);
    clk: in std_logic;
    rst: in std_logic;
    q: out std_logic_vector(WIDTH-1 downto 0)
);
end FF_D_Vector;
 architecture flow of FF_D_Vector is
component FF_D
    port(
        d, clk, rst: in std_logic;q: out std_logic
    );
end component;
begin
    stages: for i in WIDTH-1 downto 0 generate
        FF_D_i: FF_D port map(d(i),clk,rst,q(i));
    end generate;
    end flow;
```

Fifo buffer:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
package array_type is
type std_logic_vector_array is array (natural range <>) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0); 
end package;
  library IEEE;
 use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
 use IEEE.numeric_std.all;
 use work.array_type.all;

 entity FIFO_Buffer is
generic (WIDTH : INTEGER := 8);
port ( 
    Tx_data: in std_logic_vector(WIDTH-1 downto 0);
    Write_enable: in std_logic;
    Read_enable: in std_logic;
    clk: in std_logic;
    rst: in std_logic;
    Full: out std_logic;
    Empty: out std_logic;       
    Rx_data: out std_logic_vector(WIDTH-1 downto 0)
);
end FIFO_Buffer;

architecture Behavioral of FIFO_Buffer is
component Mux
    generic (WIDTH : INTEGER := 8);
    Port ( 
           SEL : in  STD_LOGIC;
           clk : in  STD_LOGIC;
           A   : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (WIDTH-1 downto 0);
           B   : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (WIDTH-1 downto 0);
           X   : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (WIDTH-1 downto 0));
end component;


component Demux
    generic (WIDTH : INTEGER := 8; CONTROLLER : INTEGER:= 2);
    Port ( 
       SEL : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (CONTROLLER-1 downto 0);
       clk : in  STD_LOGIC;
       A   : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (WIDTH-1 downto 0);
       X   : out std_logic_vector_array(2**CONTROLLER -1 downto 0));
end component;



component FF_D_Vector
    generic (WIDTH : INTEGER := 8);
    port ( 
    d: in std_logic_vector(WIDTH-1 downto 0);
    clk: in std_logic;
    rst: in std_logic;
    q: out std_logic_vector(WIDTH-1 downto 0)
);
end component;

signal Write_index: std_logic_vector(1 downto 0):="00";
signal Shift: std_logic_vector(2 downto 0):="000";
signal c: std_logic_vector_array(2**2 -1 downto 0);
signal d: std_logic_vector_array(2 downto 0);
signal e: std_logic_vector_array(2 downto 0);
signal mem_out: std_logic_vector(WIDTH-1 downto 0);
signal counter: std_logic_vector(1 downto 0):="00";





signal clk_ff: std_logic;

begin


DEMX:Demux port map(Write_index,clk,Tx_data,c);

stages1: for i in 2 downto 0 generate
  MX_i:Mux port map(shift(i),clk,c(i),e(i),d(i));
end generate;

FFDV_0:FF_D_Vector port map(d(0),clk_ff,rst,mem_out);
FFDV_3:FF_D_Vector port map(c(3),clk_ff,rst,e(2));
stages2: for i in 2 downto 1 generate
FFDV_i:FF_D_Vector port map(d(i),clk_ff,rst,e(i-1));
end generate;



process (clk,rst,Write_enable,Read_enable)
begin
if (counter="11") then
        Full<='1';
    else
        Full<='0';
    end if;
    if (counter="00") then
        Empty<='1';
    else
        Empty<='0';
end if;
clk_ff<=clk and Read_enable;
Write_index<= counter;
    if (rising_edge(clk)) then
    clk_ff<=clk and Read_enable;
Write_index<= counter;
        if (rst='0') then
        elsif (Write_enable='1' and Read_enable='0') then
            if (counter/="11") then
                counter <=std_logic_vector(unsigned(counter) + "01");
            end if;
        elsif (Write_enable='0' and Read_enable='1') then
            if (counter/="00") then
                Rx_data<=mem_out;
                Shift(0)<=counter(0) or counter(1);
                Shift(1)<=counter(0);
                Shift(2)<=counter(0) and counter(1);
                
                
                
                
                counter <=std_logic_vector(unsigned(counter) - "01");
            end if;
        end if;
    end if;
    
 end process;





end Behavioral;
```

Test banch for Fifo buffer

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

ENTITY FIFO_Buffer_test is
end FIFO_Buffer_test;

architecture behavior of FIFO_Buffer_test is
constant T_CLK   : time := 10 ns;
constant T_RESET : time := 25 ns;
constant WIDTH : INTEGER := 8;
COMPONENT FIFO_Buffer
    PORT (
        Tx_data: in std_logic_vector(WIDTH-1 downto 0);
        Write_enable: in std_logic;
        Read_enable: in std_logic;
        clk: in std_logic;
        rst: in std_logic;
        Full: out std_logic;
        Empty: out std_logic;
        Rx_data: out std_logic_vector(WIDTH-1 downto 0)
    );
END COMPONENT;
signal Tx_data_tb: std_logic_vector(WIDTH-1 downto 0);
signal Write_enable_tb: std_logic;
signal Read_enable_tb: std_logic;
signal Full_tb:std_logic;
signal Empty_tb:std_logic;
signal Rx_data_tb:std_logic_vector(WIDTH-1 downto 0);

signal clk_tb : std_logic := '0'; 
signal rst_tb  : std_logic := '0';
signal end_sim : std_logic := '1';




BEGIN
    clk_tb <= (not(clk_tb) and end_sim) after T_CLK / 2; 
    rst_tb <= '1' after T_RESET;
    FIFO_Buffer_1: FIFO_Buffer PORT 







 MAP(Tx_data=>Tx_data_tb,Write_enable=>Write_enable_tb,
 Read_enable=>Read_enable_tb,clk=>clk_tb,rst=>rst_tb 
 ,Full=>Full_tb,Empty=>Empty_tb,Rx_data=>Rx_data_tb);
 d_process: process(clk_tb, rst_tb)
    variable t : integer := 0;
  begin
    if(rst_tb = '0') then
      Tx_data_tb    <= "00000000";
      t := 0;
    elsif(rising_edge(clk_tb)) then
    case(t) is
    when 40 => end_sim <= '0';
    when 5 => Tx_data_tb<="00011010"  ; Write_enable_tb<='1' ; Read_enable_tb<='0';
    when 6 => Tx_data_tb<="11100010"  ; Write_enable_tb<='1' ; Read_enable_tb<='0';
    when 7 => Tx_data_tb<="00101010"  ; Write_enable_tb<='1' ; Read_enable_tb<='0';
    --when 8 => Tx_data_tb<="00000011"  ; Write_enable_tb<='1' ; Read_enable_tb<='0';
    when 10 => Tx_data_tb<="11100011"  ; Write_enable_tb<='1' ; Read_enable_tb<='0';
    when 13 => Write_enable_tb<='0';Read_enable_tb<='1';
    when 16 => Write_enable_tb<='0';Read_enable_tb<='1';
    when 20 => Write_enable_tb<='0';Read_enable_tb<='1';
    when 35 => Write_enable_tb<='0';Read_enable_tb<='1';
    when 38 => Write_enable_tb<='0';Read_enable_tb<='1';
    
    when others => Write_enable_tb<='0';Read_enable_tb<='0';
    end case;
    t := t + 1;
    end if;
  end process;





   end behavior;
```

So, the problem is that when i try (as you can see in testbanch) to full fifo buffer inserting 4 std_logic_vector and after i try to read all data stored, the third vector is lost and the output is the first, the second and the 4° one. You know why? Thanks

Comment: Just out of interest, why have you implemented your FiFo in this way? Is there a need for you to specify the individual flip flops (in this case as vectors). You could massively simplify your code by re-writing it to infer your memory elements. This would make it much easier to read and reduce the likelihood of errors.

Comment: how should i implement my fifo? Do you have any advice?

Comment: First, I would draw a block diagram of what a FIFO is. At it's heart a FIFO is simply a dual port RAM with pointers, that are not accessible by anything else, to point towards the next read and write locations. There are plenty of dual port ram designs floating around - a good example is in the Quartus Handbook. The key that will remove your seperate flip flops is the declaration of an array of std_logic_vector which sets your memory size.

Comment: Without peering through the voluminous detail [a write has occurred while the FIFO is full](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1ex6.jpg). With modern synthesis tools an [RTL description using integer pointers is possible](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7107lmktlha1t8d/single_clk_fifo_tb.vhdl?dl=1).